# URI extract including trailing square bracket ]

Tags: ruby

Using URI.extract to identify and deal with urls inside text (emails in this example).

A slightly annoying feature is that when extracting via schemes

```
urls = URI.extract(text, ['http', 'https', 'cid','mailto'])
```

Some of them come back with a trailing square bracket if they're included in the text with brackets around them.

e.g.

```
text = "Here's a link [mailto:bob@bob.com]"
urls = URI.extract(text, ['http', 'https', 'cid','mailto'])
=> ["mailto:bob@bob.com]"]
```

Noting that trailing closing bracket which then breaks any url parser that I use.

Is there a sensible way to stop that?

The documentation for URI.extract is sort of annoyingly short.

Comment: Is there any danger in using url.chomp("]")? I'm pretty sure that shouldn't be in URLs but there's always some edge case that bites you on the bum

Comment: Technically brackets are allowed in a URI, so `extract` is not malfunctioning. (In fact, Rails uses them a lot such as `var[]=`). However, the 'mailto:' scheme is defined in a different RFC and probably doesn't allow them there. `URI` may not be that sophisticated.

Comment: Interestingly I only tend to get errors around mailto: and cid: type links. Perhaps that might explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed something, but very simple text substitution could help? If you are familiar with `tr` unix tool, there's also `String#tr` for Ruby:

```
urls.map { |s| s.tr('[]', '') }
=> ["mailto:bob@bob.com"]
```

Comment: I thought about using chomp for this. 
My concern, I think, is that perhaps we only want to remove an unmatched square bracket.

Comment: True, in that case `urls.map { |s| s.chomp(']') }` would suffice.

Comment: Though that would still delete the end bracket if the brackets were matched. Sort of leaves me uneasy.... e.g. http://somesite.com/file[1]

Comment: Yup. I tend to use heavier solutions than necessary, so I sort of implied user does not want to have any brackets in any of those values :) Yes, more robust solution would remove trailing bracket and only in case brackets in the original string don't balance.